# How to properly setup GraphQL with Spring boot and PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, graphql-java, graphiql

I have the following issues.

1. `introspection request failed : 404` error when trying to send requests to `http://localhost:8080/graphql` using the [altair graphql client.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1MQa.png)
2. `http://localhost/graphiql` is [not accessible.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/116Y4.png)

I am new to GraphQL in Spring boot. I am using JDK 17 and IntelliJ Community Edition.

I want to make a GraphQL + Spring boot app with Postgresql. Using the Spring Initializr, I created a project and added the following [dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5XSaO.png).

I also added the following to the **application.properties** file.

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jackson.serialization.fail-on-empty-beans=false
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/demo
spring.datasource.username=demo
spring.datasource.password=demo
```

When I start this application, I get the following output:

```
...
Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
Started JavaSpringGraphqlApplication in 4.203 seconds (process running for 4.607)
```

and when I paste `http://localhost:8080/graphql` in altair, the console shows the following lines

```
...
Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
Completed initialization in 2 ms
```

I have worked with Nestjs + GraphQL and it works fine but with Spring boot I can't understand what I am doing wrong. Can someone help me set up this to the point where I can

1. set the `localhost:8080/graphql` in altair.
2. access graphiql or graphql playground.

Comment: Please [do not post a link to a painting of the code or configuration](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/1048572)! You can [edit] your question to include the code as [formatted text](/help/formatting).

Answer (score 2):

Ok Let me try help you get setup:

1. go to https://start.spring.io and choose

   - Maven
   - Java
   - latest stable Spring Boot Version(currently 3.1.3)
   - Add your Project Metadata
   - packaging: War (later, when you have everything running, you can change to jar)
   - Java: 17
   - Click on Add Dependencies
   - Search for "Spring for GraphQL" and add it
   - (optional)Search for "Spring Boot DevTools", add it
   - Click Generate -> download and unzip that file.
   - Open you favorite IDE und import that folder as an existing Maven Project into your workspace.
   - Try to run your Spring Boot Application to see if everything is working, in my case i have to run DemoApplication(annotated with @SpringBootApplication)
   - output: Started DemoApplication in 10.229 seconds (process running for 12.347)
2. add the following lines to your "application.properties"

```
    spring.graphql.path= /graphql  
    spring.graphiql.enabled= true  
    spring.graphiql.path= /graphiql
```

3. In the same folder where your "application.properties" is located you will find a folder called "graphql". Lets create a file called "query.graphqls" and add following lines to it:

---

```
    type Query{  
      people: [Person]  
    }
```

---

4. Lets create a folder und "graphql" folder called "person" or(whatever) under that folder create a file called "personType.graphqls". My File looks like this:

---

```
    type Person{  
      id: ID!  
      name: String  
      surname: String  
    }
```

---

5. now lets create a class called Person, I will put all my classes in the same package:

---

```
    public class Person {
      private String id;
      private String name;
      private String surname;
      
      public Person() {  
      
      }  
      public Person(String id, String name, String surname) {  
        this();  
        setId(id);  
        setName(surname);  
        setSurname(surname);  
      }
      public String getId() {  
        return id;  
      }  
      public void setId(String id) {  
        this.id = id;  
      }  
      public String getName() {  
        return name;  
      }  
      public void setName(String name) {  
        this.name = name;  
      }  
      public String getSurname() {  
        return surname;  
      }  
      public void setSurname(String surname) {  
        this.surname = surname;  
      }  
    }
```

---

6. Now lets create a Controller, that handles the requests, in my case I will just modify my Application Entry Class like this:

---

```
    @SpringBootApplication
    @Controller
    public class DemoApplication {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
    
    @QueryMapping
    public List<Person> people(){//make sure that this function signature and name is same with the one in query.graphqls
        
      return Arrays.asList(
                new Person("M.A.", "Muhammad","Ali"),
                new Person("M.T.", "Mike","Tython"),
                new Person("F.M.", "Floyd","Mayweather")
                );
        
      }

    }
```

---

7. Test your endpoints:
   http://localhost:8080/graphql (use Postman or Curl)
   http://localhost:8080/graphiql (use Browser)

I hope this helps you get started!